# Tell Swashbuckle to only look for controllers that have the ApiControllerAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swashbuckle

I'm working on a Web MVC project and inside it I want to have some api controllers for external apps to use.

My API controllers have the `ApiController` attribute on them.

Unfortunately, Swashbuckle picks up ALL the controllers/actions.
Is there a way to tell it to only look for Api controllers?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you deveop with asp.net core mvc or asp.net mvc? If it is asp.net core, what is .net core version and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` version? I made a test with asp.net core 2.2 and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` 4.0.1, it will only generate the method for `ApiController`. In addition, you may try to refer https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/153#issuecomment-213342771

Answer (score 4):

You can put this in the controller you want to hide from Swashbuckle

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class UserController : Controller
```

Comment: It's a valid solution but I'll have to put that in all my controllers, which is a bit too tiring...

Comment: Maybe you can create your own `BaseController` which inherits from  `Controller` and in it put the `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`, and then replace the `Controller` in your controllers that you want to be ignored with the new `BaseController`.